# Way to tell Visual Studio to automatically load certain references?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, assemblies, reference

Say I have low-level utility assemblies with some basic classes.

Then I have other higher-level assemblies which use those classes, potentially taking them as parameters and returning them.

Now, at the application level in the solution, if you add a higher-level assembly which uses lower-level assemblies in this manner, if you don't add references to the lower-level assemblies, the application will not compile.

Is there a way to indicate that a reference to an assembly *requires* other references to be exist or be added?

Comment: +1 I've been wondering this as well. IMO a single reference should be enough

Comment: If you have ReSharper, it will show a hint as soon as you use a type that you don't have a reference for, and there's a quick-fix menu to easily add the reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a NuGet package, and use the command line to add a reference to your assembly

http://nuget.codeplex.com/